# OCaml compilation with corebuild

Tags: ocaml, ocamllex, menhir

I currently have a project (Go to Python compiler) with the following files

```
ast.ml
parser.mly
lex.mll
weeder.ml
prettyPrint.ml
main.ml
```

Here are the dependencies:

```
parser: ast
lexer: parser, Core, Lexing
weeder: ast
prettyPrint: ast
main: ast, lex, parser, weeder, prettyPrint
```

I try to compile doing the following which should work according to the documentation I read:

```
$ menhir parser.mly
> Warning: you are using the standard library and/or the %inline keyword. We
  recommend switching on --infer in order to avoid obscure type error messages.

$ ocamllex lex.mll
> 209 states, 11422 transitions, table size 46942 bytes

$ ocamlbuild -no-hygiene main.native
> File "parser.mli", line 77, characters 56-59:
  Error: Unbound type constructor ast
  Command exited with code 2.
  Compilation unsuccessful after building 6 targets (2 cached) in 00:00:00.
```

ast.ml contains a list of type declarations in which I have a

```
type ast = ...
```

I spent a few hours now reading doc for ocamlfind, corebuild and ocamlopt and nothing. At some point it compiled by what seemed like a mere coincidence and never worked again. I'm open to using any tool.

Here is what is in parser.mly

```
%{
  open Ast

  exception ParserError of string

  let rec deOptionTypeInList tupleList =
    match tupleList with
      | [] -> []
      | (a, Some t)::tl -> (a, t)::(deOptionTypeInList tl)
      | _ -> raise (ParserError "no type given in type declaration")
%}

[ ... long list of tokens ... ]

%type <ast> prog (* that seems to be the problem *)
%type <string> packDec
%type <dec> dec
%type <dec> subDec
[...]

%start prog

[ ... rules ... ]
```

And here is the line, the very last, that is refereed to in the error message.

```
val prog: (Lexing.lexbuf -> token) -> Lexing.lexbuf -> (ast)
```

Comment: You are going to need to show a bit more than that, in particular the parser module.

Comment: I added what I think is important in parser.mly and the line which fails in parser.mli according to ocamlbuild

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `open Ast` construct will not be exported to the `.mli` file where the type of symbols are mentioned. Try using

```
%type <Ast.ast>
```

Edit: also, your build commands are weird. You should not call `ocamllex` and `menhir` manually, and consequently not need `-no-hygiene`. Remove all generated files and just do

```
ocamlbuild -use-menhir main.byte
```

Comment: To add to @gasche answer, from the menhir manual :
_A header is a piece of OCaml code, surrounded with %{ and %}. It is copied verbatim at the beginning of the .ml file._
This means that this code is not copied in the .mli file. The reason is, you don't want your parser specific functions to be available to other modules.